# Why its rotation is on ellipse shape

Tags: html, css, css-animations

So I had this animation name "orbitmercury" which suppose to rotate in circle shape but for some reason it is on elliptical orbit

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: black;
}

#sun {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    border: 1 solid red;
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

#mercury {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    top: 50%;
    left: 48%;
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    border: 1 solid black;
    background: gray;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: orbitmercury 2s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes orbitmercury {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg) translate(10rem);
    }
    to {

        transform:  rotate(360deg) translate(10rem);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="sun">  
</div>

<div id="mercury">  
</div>
```

I actually just saw this on yt and I decided to try it for myself but for some reason its on ellipse orbit. I also didnt know that the rotate() can go rotate from its orig position.

My apologies for this dumb question of mine Im still learning CSS animation. Please excuse my poor grammar as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you error is coming from the missing transform translate (used to move the origin point of your div and put it in the middle.)
I tried to add it on both of the planets and it look like it's working like that.

```
#sun {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
    border: 1 solid red;
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

#mercury {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 98;
    top: calc(50% - 0.5rem);
    left: calc(50% - 0.5rem);
    width: 1rem;
    height: 1rem;
    border: 1 solid black;
    background: gray;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: orbitmercury 2s linear infinite;
}
```

More detail: https://codepen.io/ColinMsd/pen/YzRWXLZ

**EDIT :**
Should be better now just add to change the mercury position with the proper height/width.

Comment: thanks but its still not on perfect circle orbit

Comment: Should be good now :) I've edited the position of the mercury planet and added a test circle so you can verify the animation is circular ( feel free to edit the codepen and remove the test circle)

Comment: thanks man. I just one to ask why is there an excess 0.5 rem on my top and left?

Comment: No problem ! To center again your planet as i did with the first solution except as your animation impact the translate the value of it wasn't right. By putting it directly in the position you are sure it's well centered.
Ps: To get that value i just divided your width /2 for left and height/2 for top

Comment: Sorry for being annoying but why do I need to divide the half of the size of my element to my position to get it right? Does the size of element affect my positioning?

Comment: Cause basically the point of origin of your element is in top left. By setting the position with this calcul you are slightly moving the position so it correspond to a centered origin point